# How to solve migration problem in sugar crm?

Tags: sugarcrm

There is a problem  i was using suagrcrm 5.5 version and when i upgrade the sugarcrm version to 6.2 then on the dashlets no delete, edit and refresh images occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the option "Prevent user customizable Homepage layout:" under Admin >> System Settings.

Answer (score 0):

They only appear when you hover over the dashlet menu bar.

Comment: i got the result actually some files are missing when we upgrade the system